# How to connect laravel to sql server via API using mac OS?

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I want to connect laravel with sql server without having any changes in .env or database.php in cofig folder.

Comment: There is no other way to connect laravel. Because it is a MVC format  we need to follow.

Comment: @HeangRethdaro Why do you refuse to change values in `.env` file (that file is made just to values be set as appropriate)?

Comment: Dear @Gurpal singh, I mean I want to have an api connection to communicate between laravel and sql server, because I have my own database in local machine and I want live data to public.

Dear Tpojka if we config database connection in .env file, this is not api connection right. I really wish we can connect sql server as api connection, But I really don't know how to make them.